# Iterar un array React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

queria saber como podia iterar sobre el array que estoy trayendo con fetch, pero no necesito todo ya que me trae como 50 items y solo quiero usar 10, lo hice con un for pero cuando le hago un console log me tira "undefined"

```
       const Api = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.jikan.moe/v3/top/manga")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .then((res) => setName(res.top));
  });
  for (let i = name.length; i <= 4; i++) {
    console.log(name[i]);
  }

  return <div>{/* <p>{title}</p> */}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! lee sobre promesas.. tu codigo es asincronico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo tienes en este bucle:

```js
 for (let i = name.length; i <= 4; i++) {
    console.log(name[i]);
  }
```

Le estás ordenando al bucle `for` que empiece a contar desde `name.lenght` (que vale 50) hasta que `i` valga 4 o menos. Naturalmente nunca entra en el bucle dado que `i` siempre vale más de 4.

De todas formas, te propongo que eches un vistazo al siguiente código, donde *"cortamos"* el array con `slice` dentro del `fetch`, con lo que ya no tienes que utilizar el bucle `for`:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [mangas, setMangas] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.jikan.moe/v3/top/manga")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      if (res.top) {
        // Pasamos unicamente los primeros 10 mangas
        setMangas(res.top.slice(0, 10))
      } else {
        throw new Error('Los datos remotos son incompletos.')
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      // Mostramos el error en la consola.
      // Aquí también podemos mostrar información del error al usuario
      console.trace(e)
    }) 
  }, []);

  return <ul>
    {mangas.map(manga => (
      <li key={manga.mal_id}>
        {manga.title}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```